# Where to put downloaded nltk data to solve HTTP Error 403 problem

Tags: python-3.x, nltk

I am facing HTTP Error 403 Forbidden problem when doing `nltk.download('averaged_perceptron_tagger')`. I searched online and found below workaround (I tried it out manually since I am not familiar with command line).

```
wget https://github.com/nltk/nltk_data/archive/gh-pages.zip
unzip gh-pages.zip
mv nltk_data-gh-pages/ $PATH_TO_NLTK_DATA
```

Basically, I went to https://github.com/nltk/nltk_data/archive/gh-pages.zip, download and upzip the folder, **but I am not sure where I should place the unzipped folder?**
I created a new folder called `nltk_data` in below several locations and put the unzipped folder in it.

But when I tried to run some Python code, e.g. `nltk.pos_tag('xxxxxyyyyy')`, I still run into below error. Why did it still say resource not found when I already put the folder there?

```
LookupError: 
**********************************************************************
  Resource averaged_perceptron_tagger not found.
  Please use the NLTK Downloader to obtain the resource:

  >>> import nltk
  >>> nltk.download('averaged_perceptron_tagger')
  
  For more information see: https://www.nltk.org/data.html
  Attempted to load taggers/averaged_perceptron_tagger/averaged_perceptron_tagger.pickle

  Searched in:
    - 'C:\\Users\\myname/nltk_data'
    - 'C:\\Users\\myname\\Anaconda3\\nltk_data'
    - 'C:\\Users\\myname\\Anaconda3\\share\\nltk_data'
    - 'C:\\Users\\myname\\Anaconda3\\lib\\nltk_data'
    - 'C:\\Users\\myname\\AppData\\Roaming\\nltk_data'
    - 'C:\\nltk_data'
    - 'D:\\nltk_data'
    - 'E:\\nltk_data'
**********************************************************************
```

Comment: Put it in any path that was mentioned in the message. Inside `nltk_data` folder would look like this: `chunkers/  corpora/  taggers/  tokenizers/`